# Do not quote arguments to command with subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to pass a glob pattern to ffmpeg via `subprocess.check_output()`. This appears to be having an issue as the output is what I would expect if the pattern was passed within quotes.

Example:

```py
subprocess.check_output([ffmpeg_path, '-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i', '/tmp/*?(jpg|jpeg)'...])
```

This results in:

> /tmp/*?(jpg|jpeg): No such file or directory.

Which is different than the "no matches" error I receive if run this command via the shell. What appears to be happening is that the command is being composed as

```sh
ffmpeg -pattern_type 'glob' -i '/tmp/*?(jpg|jpeg)'
```

and what I'd want is (note lack of quotations)

```sh
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i /tmp/*?(jpg|jpeg)
```

Something of note is that I am passing in the directory so `directory + '/*?(jpg|jpeg)'` is what is in the list being passed to `check_output()`. This may be part of the issue.

How would I prevent this, or how would I pass the raw arguments desired?

ffmpeg version when running on development machine:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
```

and using the ffmpeg amd64 static build when deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Your wildcard pattern uses a `bash` extension, which `ffmpeg` probably doesn't support.

Instead, use multiple `-i` options, with standard wildcards.

```
subprocess.check_output([ffmpeg_path, '-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i', '/tmp/*.jpg', '-i', '/tmp/*.jpeg', ...])
```

There are no actual quotes being added. When you use `shell=False`, the list elements are passed as is directly to the program, without going through a shell, so no quoting is needed. The documentation doesn't explain it accurately -- what they mean is that this acts *as if* you were quoting all the arguments.

Comment: Using multiple `-i` is not working, at least not with newer versions (I tested with FFmpeg version 4.3.1). The meaning of multiple `-i` is multiple input streams and not multiple input lists of images. When using `subprocess.check_output([ffmpeg_path, '-y', '-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i', '*.jpg', '-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i', '*.jpeg', 'test.mp4'])` there is no error, but the `*.jpeg` files are ignored (we may solve it using `concat` filter, but it complicates things).

Answer (score 1):

The quotes is not the issue, the FFmpeg **glob syntax** is a little different than the one you are using.

Here is an example for a correct syntax:

```
subprocess.check_output([ffmpeg_path, '-vcodec', 'mjpeg', '-f', 'image2', '-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i', '/tmp/*?{jpg,jpeg}', 'test.mp4'])
```

---

- Specify the video codec: `'-vcodec', 'mjpeg'`.
  I suppose FFmpeg fails to identify the codec automatically due to the pattern.
- Specify the muxer format: `'-f', 'image2'`.
  I suppose FFmpeg fails to identify the format automatically due to the pattern.
- Use the following syntax: `'/tmp/*?{jpg,jpeg}'` (instead of `/tmp/*?(jpg|jpeg)`).
  The pattern matches the rules of [Bash Gglobing](https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/).

---

The command line includes the quotes, and it's working with the them.

```
ffmpeg -vcodec mjpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i "/tmp/*?{jpg,jpeg}" -vcodec libx264 test.mp4
```

---

### Testing:

I tested the Python code under Ubuntu 18.04 (using VirtualBox).

Using command line (console):

Changing directory to `/tmp` (in Ubuntu it supposed to be existed):
`cd /tmp`

Checking FFmpeg version:
`ffmpeg -version`

Output:
`ffmpeg version 3.1.3-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers`
`built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-1) 20160803`
(I think it's the default version of Ubuntu 18.04).

Creating 10 (synthetic pattern) files with jpg extension and 7 files with jpeg extension:
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 %d.jpg`
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=7 %d.jpeg`

List jpg and jpeg files:
`ls *?{jpg,jpeg}`

Output:
`10.jpg  1.jpeg  1.jpg  2.jpeg  2.jpg  3.jpeg  3.jpg  4.jpeg  4.jpg  5.jpeg  5.jpg  6.jpeg  6.jpg  7.jpeg  7.jpg  8.jpg  9.jpg`

Encoding the files (in command line):
`ffmpeg -y -vcodec mjpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i "/tmp/*?{jpg,jpeg}" -vcodec libx264 test.mp4`

Verifying there are 17 video frames using FFprobe:
`ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -print_format csv test.mp4`

Output:
`stream,17`

delete test.mp4:
`rm test.mp4`

---

Python test (still in folder `/tmp`, and console):

Checking Python version:
`python3 --version`

Output:
`Python 3.7.4`

Copy `test.py` into `/tmp` folder.
Content of `test.py` (the file is in the same folder: `/tmp`):

```
import subprocess

ffmpeg_path = 'ffmpeg'

subprocess.check_output([ffmpeg_path, '-vcodec', 'mjpeg', '-f', 'image2', '-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i', '/tmp/*?{jpg,jpeg}', 'test.mp4'])
```

Executing the Python script form shell:
`python3 test.py`

Output:
`ffmpeg version 3.1.3-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers`
...
`frame=   17`

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Of note is that I reduced the example to the parts that I was able to figure out weren't working. I appreciate the `-vcodec` tip, but I do specify the other options in a way that works (with the Bash extension).
I'll check with the new globbing pattern.

Comment: I am limiting the scope of my answer to the parts that are in your post, and I can't promise anything about the parts that you didn't post. Please test it as in my answer first.

Comment: I tried this pattern but I still get the same result. The output is the ffmpeg version and configuration options followed by `/long/absolute/path/*?{jpeg,jpeg}: No such file or directory`
If I stop this script via a debugger I can verify the existence of the directory and files via `ls`, as I also do with `os.path.isdir` and `os.listdir` in the script.

Of note may be that there is no file with the `jpg` extension.

Comment: Well... I tested it in Ubuntu 18.04 and FFmpeg version 4.3.1. Is it working with just `*.jpg` instead of `*?{jpg,jpeg}` ?

Comment: When testing, I didn't use the path `\tmp`, I used some other full path. The directory had jpeg and jpg files.

Comment: I have updated my post with the testing procedure. If it's not helping you, it may still help somebody else... In case you are not managed to find a solution using glob pattern, you may write the images to `stdin` pipe of FFmpeg sub-process (using a for loop).

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I ended up using the `glob` package and writing the files to an input file. I think passed that as the input to ffmpeg.

Comment: Can you please tell what operation system are you using, and what is the version of FFmpeg? I am curious why isn't it working... Instead of writing the files to an input file, consider writing the files to stdin pipe of FFmpeg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241696/discussion-between-toothlessrebel-and-rotem).